# Parsing simple log files in Julia vs Python

Tags: python, parsing, logging, julia

I wrote a log parser in Python and Julia. The Python version takes about 8 seconds to process 350 files, while the Julia version takes about 8 seconds to *compile*, after which it takes over 20 seconds to process 350 log files.

I wrote the original parser in Python several months ago, with regex, a custom class, and lots of methods for detailed analysis. I recently wrote a Julia version with regex, a custom type, and only a single analysis function (the only one I regularly used). I then wrote a very trimmed-down version of each parser, using only basic string functions. I'm experienced with Python but not with Julia, and I can't figure out why the Julia version is so slow (even discounting the compilation time). If I can AoT compile the Julia script, dramatically reduce its run time, and package it into a native x86/64 executable, it might be worth using.

What am I doing wrong with this Julia script? How can I make it faster?

The Python version:

```
import datetime
import sys
import os
import tzlocal

min_date = tzlocal.get_localzone().localize(datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 1))
min_date -= min_date.utcoffset()
day = min_date
keys = ['Contraband', 'Dilithium', 'Dilithium Ore', 'Energy Credits']
dct = {key:0 for key in keys}
files = sorted(f for f in os.listdir() if f[:5]=="Chat_")
l = len(files)
try:
    with open('lastlog.txt') as f:
        lastlog = f.read()
except (FileNotFoundError, PermissionError):
    lastlog = ''

print('Date', *keys, sep='\t')
for counter,fname in enumerate(files):
    if fname >= lastlog:
        print('Processing {} out of {}...'.format(counter, l), end='\r', file=sys.stderr)
        with open(fname, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            for line in f:
                if (line[26:70] == ",0,NumericReceived@,@,,,System]You received " and
                    ('Dilithium' in line or 'Energy Credits' in line)):
                    quantity,item = line.strip()[70:].split(None, 1)
                    quantity = int(quantity.replace(',', ''))
                    if item == 'Refined Dilithium':
                        item = 'Dilithium'
                elif line[26:66] == ",0,NumericReceived@,@,,,System]You sold ":
                    item = 'Energy Credits'
                    quantity = int(line.rsplit(None, 3)[1].replace(',', ''))
                elif line[26:78] == ",0,NumericConversionSuccess@,@,,,System]You refined ":
                    item = 'Dilithium'
                    quantity = int(line[78:-11].replace(',', ''))
                elif (line[26:56] == ",0,NumericLost@,@,,,System]You" and
                        (line[56:62] == " lost " or line[56:63] == " spent ") and 
                      ('Dilithium' in line or 'Energy Credits' in line)):
                    quantity,item = line[62:].strip().split(None, 1)
                    quantity = -int(quantity.replace(',', ''))
                    if item == 'Refined Dilithium':
                        item = 'Dilithium'
                elif line[26:83] == ',0,ItemReceived@,@,,,System]Items acquired: Contraband x ':
                    quantity = int(line[70:].rsplit(None, 1)[1].replace(',', ''))
                    item = 'Contraband'
                elif line[26:79] == ",0,ItemReceived@,@,,,System]Item acquired: Contraband":
                    quantity = 1
                    item = 'Contraband'
                else:
                    continue
                dt = tzlocal.get_localzone().localize(datetime.datetime(year=int(line[11:15]), month=int(line[15:17]),
                     day=int(line[17:19]), hour=int(line[20:22]), minute=int(line[22:24]), second=int(line[24:25])))
                dt -= dt.utcoffset()
                if dt.day != day.day and day != min_date:
                    print('{}-{}-{}'.format(day.year,
                                            day.month,
                                            day.day),
                          *(dct[k] for k in keys), sep='\t')
                    dct = {key:0 for key in keys}
                day = dt
                if item in dct:
                    dct[item] += quantity

print('{}-{}-{}'.format(dt.year,
                        dt.month,
                        dt.day),
      *(dct[k] for k in keys), sep='\t')

print('\nDone.', file=sys.stderr)

last = files[-1][5:15]
current = files[-1]
for fname in files[::-1]:
    current = fname
    if fname[5:15] != last:
        break

with open('lastlog.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(current)
```

The Julia version:

```
import TimeZones

function GetTotals()
    zone = TimeZones.localzone() # get local time zone
    min_date = TimeZones.astimezone(
                TimeZones.ZonedDateTime(
                    DateTime(2002,1,1), zone),
                        TimeZones.TimeZone("UTC")) # set local minimum date as UTC
    day = min_date
    k = String["Contraband", "Dilithium", "Dilithium Ore", "Energy Credits"]
    dct = Dict{String,Int64}(key=>0 for key in k)
    files = sort([f for f in readdir() if f[1:5]=="Chat_"])
    l = length(files)

    if isfile("lastlog.txt")
        lastlog = open("lastlog.txt") do f
            readstring(f)
        end
    else
        lastlog = ""
    end

    println("Date", '\t', join(k, '\t'))
    for (counter,fname) in enumerate(files)
        if fname >= lastlog # "Chat_2016-11-04" < fname < "Chat_2016-11-12" 
            print(STDERR, "Processing ", counter, " out of ", l, "...\r")
            open(fname) do f
                for line in eachline(f)
                    if length(line) > 70 && line[27:70] == ",0,NumericReceived@,@,,,System]You received " &&
                        (contains(line, "Dilithium") || contains(line, "Energy Credits"))
                        quantity,item = split(strip(line)[71:end], ' '; limit=2)
                        quantity = parse(Int, replace(quantity, ",", ""))
                        if item == "Refined Dilithium"
                            item = "Dilithium"
                        end
                    elseif length(line) > 66 && line[27:66] == ",0,NumericReceived@,@,,,System]You sold "
                        item = "Energy Credits"
                        quantity = parse(Int, replace(rsplit(line, ' '; limit=4)[2], ",", ""))
                    elseif length(line) > 78 && line[27:78] == ",0,NumericConversionSuccess@,@,,,System]You refined "
                        item = "Dilithium"
                        quantity = parse(Int, replace(line[79:end-13], ",", ""))
                    elseif length(line) > 63 && (line[27:56] == ",0,NumericLost@,@,,,System]You" &&
                            (line[57:62] == " lost " || line[57:63] == " spent ") && 
                          (contains(line, "Dilithium") || contains(line, "Energy Credits")))
                        quantity,item = split(strip(line[63:end]), ' '; limit=2)
                        quantity = -parse(Int, replace(quantity, ",", ""))
                        if item == "Refined Dilithium"
                            item = "Dilithium"
                        end
                    elseif length(line) > 83 && line[27:83] == ",0,ItemReceived@,@,,,System]Items acquired: Contraband x "
                        quantity = parse(Int, replace(rsplit(line[71:end], ' ', limit=2)[2], ",", ""))
                        item = "Contraband"
                    elseif length(line) > 79 && line[27:79] == ",0,ItemReceived@,@,,,System]Item acquired: Contraband"
                        quantity = 1
                        item = "Contraband"
                    else
                        continue
                    end
                    dt = TimeZones.astimezone(TimeZones.ZonedDateTime(DateTime(line[12:19]*line[21:26], "yyyymmddHHMMSS"), zone), TimeZones.TimeZone("UTC"))

                    current = TimeZones.floor(dt, Dates.Day)
                    if day != current && day != min_date
                        println(Dates.format(day, "yyyy-mm-dd"),
                                '\t', join((dct[key] for key in k), '\t'))
                        dct = Dict{String,Int64}(key=>0 for key in k)
                    end
                    day = current
                    if item in keys(dct)
                        dct[item] += quantity
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    println(Dates.format(day, "yyyy-mm-dd"), '\t', join((dct[key] for key in k), '\t'))
    println(STDERR, "\nDone.")
    last = files[end][6:15]
    current = files[end]
    for fname in files[end:-1:1]
        current = fname
        if fname[6:15] != last
            break
        end
    end
    open("lastlog.txt", "w") do f
        write(f, current)
    end
end

GetTotals()
```

Comment: Are you sure it's type-stable? Have you checked `@code_warntype`? Also, `v[a:b]` in Julia creates a copy. You may want to reduce allocations by using views: `@view v[a:b]`. To handle compilation times, put the function in a module and precompile the module.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas - I tried `@code_warntype` but didn't understand the output (I can post or link it if you'd like to see it). `@view` doesn't work on strings. I added `__precompile__()` and `module MyModule` to the top of the script (and `end` at the bottom), and I'm getting the impression from the [doc](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/modules/#module-initialization-and-precompilation) that it'll only make a difference if this module is imported into another script, because it still has a long delay before producing output.

Comment: Please post the `@code_warntype`. (I notified some people in the [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia) about this too since strings aren't really my thing. But many people there could help you)

Comment: Could you put a tar of at least a sample of the log files you used, so that people can try different approaches and do profiling?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas - I've put the `@code_warntype` output into a zip file [here](http://tigerhawkt3.com/logs_and_warntype.zip), along with some sample log files.

Comment: @ScottJones - I uploaded a [zip file](http://tigerhawkt3.com/logs_and_warntype.zip) with some sample logs and the `@code_warntype` results.

Comment: `files::UNION{ARRAY{STRING,1},ARRAY{UNION{},1}}`. These lines like this (they are capitalized) show that you have a lot of not strictly typed arrays. Those will kill your performance. For this variable, you should think of using Nullables instead. That would be a start. Getting rid of these type instabilities will likely massively improve performance. Another thing you might want to do, if you can't eliminate them, is to use a function barrier.

Comment: Do you want a review of both the Python and the Julia code, or just the Julia/Python code?

Comment: @Peilonrayz - Just the Julia code. I only wrote that Python version in an attempt to get something simpler and easier to rewrite in Julia.

Comment: I'm still playing around with this, but one thing (that could be used to speed up both the Python and Julia versions) would be to not retest the same things for each case: i.e. if the line length is <= 63, just continue right away. then check if the line starts with ",0,Numeric", and then check the sub cases of "Received@,@,,,System] You ", "ConversionSuccess@,@,,,System]You refined ", and "Lost@,@,,,System]You ", and check the sub cases of those.  Also, you can add a function that takes the line, an offset, and the string to compare, and returns whether or not the string is at that offset.

Comment: It may be useful information that datetime parsing has gotten ~100x faster in master for Julia. This should help close the gap a lot.